# Why i can't see the imag inside tag?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I learn to use angularjs and bootstrap.

And in this templat:

```
<div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-4 container-fluid">
<div class="column col-lg-3">
    <img src="../img/yst.jpg" class="thumbnail logo"  alt="YST" />
</div>
</div>
```

I can't see the image. but when i insert url it work.

the error i get is:
GET http://localhost:63342/startup/img/yst.jpg 404 (Not Found)

What is the problem?

Comment: Where is the img folder stored compared to your `.html` file where you are referencing it? The above implies, that the img is one directory above the `.html` file, is that correct? If they are in the same dir, then change the source to `"img/yst.jpg"`

Comment: thanks!! it work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="../img/yst.jpg" class="thumbnail logo"  alt="YST" />
```

fix

```
 <img src="img/yst.jpg" class="thumbnail logo"  alt="YST" />
```